# NSCollectionView: Accept Drag Only Between Items, not Over

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I have a `NSCollectionView` implemented  and working fine. However, when
dragging items around to re-arrange them,  I'd like to accept drags only
between objects.

The current behaviour is that you  can drag between objects (it opens an
space) but also *over* an object.  I hope the images below speak better.
Dragging an item over  #2, for example, will put it  before #2. I'd like
to disable this and only accept drags in between.

In the images below:

1. The original state
2. Item #0 dragged *between* #1 and #2
3. Item #0 dragged *over* #2 (the result is the same)

[image: drag and drop]

Comment: Does your collection view have a delegate?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, of course.

Comment: Can you show your code where you drag, or something is relevant

Comment: @anhtu Yes, but I don't know if it makes any difference. It's very generic and big implementation of standard drag-and-drop operations. I'm not really asking about how to fix something, just how to implement :-) any specific part you need to see?

Comment: Why don't you detect it by index(indexPath.row or something similar) of cell? Or using `CGRectIntersectsRect`, just accept if it intersect with >= 2 cell in a row. Or using position of each cell to detect between, over. I think you already think about them. I just want to know the reason why don't?

Comment: @anhtu I though about an strategy to refuse the drop in those cases, but I think the problem is in another place. If I simply don't accept the drop, It will basically stop working. I want that when dragging an item over another, the space between them opens normally and the item is not set selected. But is still approved as a drop.

Comment: You really need to post your code.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi do you understand about drag and drop implementations? If so, is there an specific part you want to see? Because as I stated above, there is no problem happening. Just regular implementation. I'm asking how to implement something else. If I post a reduced version, I doubt it would help.

Comment: Your answer is exactly why you should've posted your code. It would've let us know exactly what was missing or wrong without requiring us to write a complete, contrived answer in hopes of catching what you might be missing or doing wrong. This very common operation could've been pointed out to you days ago. Help us help you.

Comment: Sorry @JoshuaNozzi , but I asked which part to see and you didn't reply in time. I won't post 300 lines of code here. Furthermore, I said that I had a complete implementation, so if one understand about collection view they automatically know that this method was implemented. And the answer was also pretty straightforward if one knows. Just adding a one line of statement in a standard method. You see that I answered without revealing any previous code. And of course this line was missing if I want to get this behavior. Thank you for your help but please be less picky with these questions.

Comment: Two people asking you to post your code is not "picky"; it's far easier to determine and describe a solution when you post your code. See also: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Sorry to turn up like this, but do you mind if I ask how you implemented those gaps (i.e. the ‘it opens a space’ part) in the first place? It’s something I’m struggling with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093314/how-to-interactively-rearrange-nscollectionview-items-while-dragging-over-them), and you seem to maybe have insight I’m missing.

Comment: @KLee I'll take a look. Unfortunately a long time has passed and I can't remember it all by heart, but I'll do my best to find this code and understand it. I hope I can help you. Once I find something, I'll let you know on your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after some more research, I found that the `validadeDrop` method has
a parameter that describes exactly that,  if the operation is over or in
between.  And since  it is  given  as a  reference, one  can change  the
parameter to overwrite  a certain behaviour. So, the solution  is to add
this check to the method:

```
- (NSDragOperation)
    collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
      validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo
     proposedIndex:(NSInteger *)proposedDropIndex
     dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation *)proposedDropOperation
{
    /* ... */

    if (*proposedDropOperation == NSCollectionViewDropOn)
        *proposedDropOperation =  NSCollectionViewDropBefore;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks i was tearing my head out on this!