# How to interactively rearrange NSCollectionView items while dragging over them?

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewlayout

Apps like Preview indicate the drop position for drag operations by interactively moving the items out of the way. Looks like this:

[image: Preview.app drag and drop behaviour]

IIRC, this is also the default behaviour of `UICollectionView` with all standard layouts. In contrast, `NSCollectionView` prefers to render an insertion indicator without repositioning the items, and I can’t quite figure out how to make it do the above. Interestingly, a screenshot in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314283/nscollectionview-accept-drag-only-between-items-not-over) seems to show the exact behaviour I want (alas, the discussion over there is unrelated).

To clarify whether – and how – the delegate is set up for drag operations:

```objectivec
- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView canDragItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths withEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}

- (id<NSPasteboardWriting>)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView pasteboardWriterForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSPasteboardItem *pasteboardItem = [[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init];
    [pasteboardItem setString:@"Whatever is fine" forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
    
    return pasteboardItem;
}

- (NSDragOperation)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo proposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull __autoreleasing *)proposedDropIndexPath dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation *)proposedDropOperation {
    *proposedDropOperation = NSCollectionViewDropBefore;
    
    return NSDragOperationMove;
}
```

My initial understanding was that layout’s `-layoutAttributesForDropTargetAtPoint:`/`-layoutAttributesForInterItemGapBeforeIndexPath:` existed for this purpose. They don’t, as they only serve to place the *indicator* which does not affect the flow of items.

To be exact, setting an arbitrary rect (in a subclassed `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`):

```objectivec
- (NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDropTargetAtPoint:(NSPoint)pointInCollectionView {
    NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [[super layoutAttributesForDropTargetAtPoint:pointInCollectionView] copy];
    attributes.frame = NSMakeRect(60, 0, 200, 200);

    return attributes;
}
```

will render the indicator at {60, 0}, but that won’t affect the items in any way.

I could, of course, extend the layout further to make it aware of dragging sessions, but that already feels like a hack, and having to manually invalidate it during the drag (let alone doing it within `-performBatchUpdates:completionHandler:` to trigger an animated response) leaves no doubt about that. Alternatively, I could manipulate items’ frames directly, but that also feels like fighting the `NSCollectionView` rather than leveraging it.

Given how widespread the pattern is, there must be a proper way of implementing it without resorting to hacks. What am I missing?

Cheers.

Comment: The documentation of `NSCollectionView` says "The collection view delegate makes decisions about behaviors. The delegate also coordinates the dragging and dropping of items.". Have you tried using any delegate methods?

Comment: Of course. Drag and drop in collections wouldn’t even work without the delegate. I’m omitting it here merely because, even in their minimal form, collection delegates tend to be uncomfortably verbose – and people increasingly Objective-C averse; but I do register pasteboard types and return `YES` in enough places to see the insertion indicator I’m describing. Do you think I should include the delegate code after all?

Comment: Is `collectionView(_:validateDrop:proposedIndexPath:dropOperation:)` implemented? Do you change `proposedDropOperation`?

Comment: Yes. I’ve updated the question to include the relevant parts of the implementation.

Comment: I don't think a drop insertion gap is supported. `[collectionView setValue:@YES forKey:@"opensDropInsertionGaps"]` does the trick but it's private API and it's a bit buggy.

Comment: Hah, that would explain why it’s seen extensively throughout macOS but not so much in third-party apps. I think you’re right, that private property wouldn’t be there in the first place if the functionality was more readily available (I should’ve thought about reflection; knew I was missing something obvious). Thanks a lot for looking into this. Do you feel like posting this as an answer so I can accept it?